# VueJs v-bind.sync on nested Object doesn(t update parent

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, parent-child

Hi everyone i'm building a huge form that should upload a huge Object with nested objects.
For more convenient source management i decided to split my form in child component and pass a v-bind.sync directive for bidirectional update but my child component isn't updating my main parent object
My parent looks like

parent.vue

```
<template>
  <ChildOne
    v-bind.sync="assetData.CUSTOM_FAAS_PROPS"
  />
  <ChildTwo
    v-bind.sync="assetData.CUSTOM_PUBLICATION_PROPS"
  />

</template>
<script>
import ChildOne from '@/components/AssetForm/ChildOne.vue'
import ChildTwo from '@/components/AssetForm/ChildOTwo.vue'
export default {
  components: {
    ChildOne ,
    ChildTwo
  },
  data: () => ({
    assetData:{
      CUSTOM_FAAS_PROPS:{
        Description:{
          en:'',
          fr:''
        },
        Input:{
          data:{
            filekey:'',
            extension:''
          }
        }
      },
      CUSTOM_PUBLICATION_PROPS:{}

     
    }
  })
}
</script>
```

And my ChildOne.vue

```
<template>
  <input
    :value="Input.data.filekey"
    @input="$emit('update:Input.data.filekey', $event), logresult($event)"
  />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    Description:{
      type: Object,
      default () {
        return {
          en:'',
          fr:''
        }
      }
    },
    Input:{
      type: Object,
      default () {
        return {
          data:{
            filekey:'',
            extension:''
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
      logresult($event){
          console.log($event)
      }
  }
```

The log result print in console the content of my text input but the parent object is not updating.
I can't figure it out how to use v-bind.sync for nested object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally went for a workaround with vuex store and mapState function